# Merge lists, group By and create a sub-list with all values from one parameter

Tags: scala, group-by

i'm trying to figure out how i achieve the following.

I have a list of tuples

```
scala> List(t1,t2,t3)
res16: List[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((1001,Test), (1002,Schnitzel), (1001,Käse))
```

What i want out of this lists is s.th. like this

```
List[(Int, Seq[java.lang.String]) = List((1001, Seq(Test, Käse)), (1002, Seq(Schnitzel)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a function `groupBy` which achieves almost what you want. E.g.,

```
val xs = List(t1, t2, t3)
val m  = xs.groupBy(_._1)
```

groups the antries of `xs` by their first components, resulting in the map

```
Map(1002 -> List((1002,Schnitzel)), 1001 -> List((1001,Test), (1001,Kaese)))
```

This does not have the type you want and also the keys are still part of the entries. This can be resolved by, e.g.,

```
val ys : List[(Int, Seq[String])] = m.mapValues(_.map(_._2)).toList
```

Comment: It would be nice to have an overloaded version of `groupBy` which supported defining a map over the values.